# Simple alternative to logbak.fatal("foo")?

Tags: java, logging

In the *Logback* exception handling framework, how are these different?

```
try {
    ...
} catch(Exception e) {
    logback.error("fatal error!");
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

how is this different from

```
try {
    ...
} catch(Exception e} {
    logback.fatal("fatal error!");
}
```

My Logger instance cannot invoke `fatal("foo")` yet for some reason or I'd test it. But before I debug this, how are the above different?

(Of course, except that being able to use "fatal()" allows for a little more control of what is logged.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using sl4j for logging which does not support fatal method as of now.
If you really want to use fatal, you should switch to log4j/log4j2 instead.

To answer on difference between ERROR and FATAL types:

- **ERROR**: The ERROR level designates error events that might still allow the application to continue running. Errors like NullPointerException or other runTimeExceptions.
- **FATAL**: The FATAL level designates very severe error events that will presumably lead the application to abort.

Hope this helps.